# Numpy: prod, what overflow really is?

Tags: numpy, overflow, product

I'm reading in the following documentation of Python:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html

> ### Notes
>
> Arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is raised
> on overflow. That means that, on a 32-bit platform:
>
> ```
> >>> x = np.array([536870910, 536870910, 536870910, 536870910])
> >>> np.prod(x)  # random 
> 16
> ```

Can somebody explain what it means that arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and how this relates to if I have a 32- or 64-bit platform?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki page explains modular arithmetic but not the relevance to numpy.

numpy ints can be signed or unsigned with 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit.

```
         Range signed        Range unsigned
 8 bit   -128 to 127         0 to 255        0 to 2**8-1
16 bit   -32768 to 32767     0 to 65535      0 to 2**16-1
32 bit   -2**31 to 2**31-1   0 to 2**32-1    Decimal 9 digits
64 bit   -2**64 to 2**64-1   0 to 2**64-1    Decimal 18/19 digits
```

It's easiest to visualise for np.int8.  Only 256 different possible values.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(256, dtype=np.int8)
print(a)

[   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44
   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74
   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89
   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104
  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119
  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127 -128 -127 -126 -125 -124 -123 -122
 -121 -120 -119 -118 -117 -116 -115 -114 -113 -112 -111 -110 -109 -108 -107
 -106 -105 -104 -103 -102 -101 -100  -99  -98  -97  -96  -95  -94  -93  -92
  -91  -90  -89  -88  -87  -86  -85  -84  -83  -82  -81  -80  -79  -78  -77
  -76  -75  -74  -73  -72  -71  -70  -69  -68  -67  -66  -65  -64  -63  -62
  -61  -60  -59  -58  -57  -56  -55  -54  -53  -52  -51  -50  -49  -48  -47
  -46  -45  -44  -43  -42  -41  -40  -39  -38  -37  -36  -35  -34  -33  -32
  -31  -30  -29  -28  -27  -26  -25  -24  -23  -22  -21  -20  -19  -18  -17
  -16  -15  -14  -13  -12  -11  -10   -9   -8   -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2 -1]
```

The numbers represented by 8 bits > 127 show as negative.

```
np.binary_repr(127, 8)
Out[11]: '01111111'

np.binary_repr(-128, 8)
Out[12]: '10000000'
```

If bit 7 is set this indicates a negative integer.

Use np.int8 to play with some numbers.

```
np.int8(17*18)   # Out[29]: 50
17*18 % 256      # Out[30]: 50  (17*18=306) Mod 256 = 50

np.int8(17*180) # Out[31]: -12
17*180 % 256    # Out[32]: 244  
np.binary_repr(244, 8)   # Out[33]: '11110100'
np.binary_repr(-12, 8)   # Out[34]: '11110100'
```

The documentation is saying that if integer arithmetic overflows it simply wraps around the number range, it doesn't raise an exception.  Replace 'wraps around' with modular.

If overflow does occur it simply produces surprising (and probably incorrect) results.

This gives a quick outline.  Use `np.int8(expr)` and `np.binary_repr( n, 8)` to play around and see what is happening.

Edit to explain bit 7

```
Bit numbers  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
     127     0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  Bit 7 not set 0 +127
    -128     1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  Bit 7 set     1 -128
      -1     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! What do you mean by «if bit 7 is set»?

Comment: @Erosennin I've editted the answer with an explanation at the end.  For each int size it's the most significant bit that is set to indicate a negative number. 7, 15, 31 or 63.